# Changing Card during the dialog node alexa-sdk

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I have searched the web already for an answer but I couldn't find one. So basically imagine the following alexa-dialog:

> 'Alexa, start SKILL'

The Alexa device should show a simple card like

> 'Hey USER. Nice to hear You.'

, ask the USER what he wants to do next
and be ready for an answer after that.

```
// To do that, I am using the following line of code: 

this.emit('askWithCard', speechOutput, speechOutput, SKILLNAME, 'Hey USER...');
```

When Alexa is listening again, imagine the user saying something like

> 'Do I have new messages?'

Alexa should then update the last card with something like

> 'You have received 2 new messages of Tom.'

and ask the USER for input again.

I have tried to just use the code mentioned above, but Alexa just does not update the card, so that even if I emit a new 'askWithCard' or 'tellWithCard', there still is the first 'Hey USER. Nice to hear you'-card shown.

**Is there any possibility to update a card?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like it only appears in the developer console. If I start the skill on my Alexa App on the phone it works just as expected.